# Syntax for dynamic key name in fetch statement

Tags: php, dynamic, var

I'm trying to modify the name of the `key` dynamically based on which rows are being fetched, but my syntax seems to be slightly off within the query. After moving the quotes around more times than I care to admit, I finally decided it was time to ask for help ;-)

```
$var = '$foo_row';
$MAX_5A = ${$var . '["MAX_5A"]'};
```

Instead of

```
$MAX_5A = $foo_row['MAX_5A'];
```

Bonus points if someone wants to explain to me the logic behind the correct syntax :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Just use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) with curly quotes to make sure PHP doesn't think this: `${$var["MAX_5A"]}`. Also note I removed the dollar sign in the string)

```
$var = 'foo_row';
      //^ dollar sign removed
$MAX_5A = ${$var}["MAX_5A"];
```

Comment: Duh :-) It's amazing how sometimes I'm so focused on the less familiar method (in this case Variable Variables) that I just assume that's where my code is off ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = 'foo';
$bar = 'var';
echo $$bar; // foo
```

Logic: A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable.

Comment: I knew that ;-) As @Rizier123 pointed out, my mistake was with the way I was declaring the var ;-)